# What Overflow do I use in CSS to scroll vertically

Tags: css, overflow

I'm getting mixed up with my overflow and I just wanted to be put in the right direction.

Comment: And overflow-x: auto; does it horizontally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `overflow-y:auto` is the one your after

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `overflow-y:`

Try something like this:

```
<div id="yourDiv" style="overflow-y:scroll;height:400px">
```

Comment: already had it set up, just need to understand which one to use, thanks though :)